# Neo4jclient, How to Unify or Merge To Different result but in same type?

Tags: merge, neo4j, cypher, union, neo4jclient

I Have problem that solved by checking two different type of relation for two same node.

For example, we have to Match section as below:

```
1. Match("(u:User)-[r:USER_IN_SITE]->(w:WebEnvir)")
    .Return(u => u.As<TUser>())
                        .Results;
  2. Match("(u:User)-[r2:USER_IN_CLOUD]->(w:WebEnvir)")
    .Return(u => u.As<TUser>())
                        .Results;
```

How Can I make merge or union between Match ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a UNION (which I'm not sure how to do it neo4jclient), but you can also do this, I think (in pure Cypher):

```
MATCH (u:User), (w:WebEnvir)
OPTIONAL MATCH
  (u)-[r:USER_IN_SITE]->(w), (u)-[r2:USER_IN_CLOUD]->(w)
RETURN u, w, collect(r), collect(r2)
```

Beware, though, because you'll be getting a full cartesian product either way (actually you'd be doing it twice with a `UNION`, I think).  Depending on how many `User` and `WebEnvir` nodes you have, that could be a really big query

Comment: Thanks @brian-Underwood , but I need to do it by Neo4jClient, anyway thanks for feedback.

Comment: Couldn't you translate the Cypher into Neo4jClient syntax?